# Using OpenSAML to verify correctness of a SAML2 federation

Tags: identity, single-sign-on, saml

I have setup a `SAML2` identity federation using opensso. I need to validate the identity
federation as follows:

**1.** Validate the user specified IDP metadata file

**2.** Issue a `SAML2` authn request to make sure that the `SP` gets a valid `SAML2` response back from the IDP.

how can I use `OpenSAML` utilities to do 1 and 2?

Comment: Have a look at my blog posts about OpenSAML http://mylifewithjava.blogspot.com/